# Can you use Github App with Beanstalk?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Being new to Git, I wanted to use a GUI (Windows based) and preferred the Github App.  However, I would like to integrate this site with a Beanstalkapp account.  I'm pretty sure this is possible, but I can't figure it out.

Inside of the Github app, I navigate to my repository.  When I choose "**Tools** > **Settings...**", I place the *Git Clone URL* for the repository provided by Beanstalk into the "**Primary Remote (origin)**" field in my Github app.

Now when I click "**Publish**" (which says "*Click to publish this branch to server*" when I hover over it) it changes to "Publishing...".  After a few seconds, I get this error:

> **server failure**
>
> The remote server disconnected.  Try again later, or if this persists, contact support@github.com

I am pretty sure I set the SSH keys up properly (never done this before).  I added the key to both the Beanstalkapp and my Github web account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**

Github creates a SSH key in the `C:/Users/username/.ssh` directory (based on my Windows 7 settings).  You must add the key that Github creates `github_rsa` to your keys in Beanstalk.

**What I was doing wrong...**

I created a SSH key *(which is very common in almost every Git Getting Started tutorial)*, and was adding that key to Beanstalk, thinking somehow my computer (or perhaps Git) would automagically use that key (I'm new to this).  Um, no. :)  The Github app creates and uses it's own key, and that's what you load into Beanstalk if you want to use that app.